# Change text color within a alert dialog box?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a alert dialog box that will ask the user a question and some of the text in the message will be lets say, red.

This is what I've tried:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        this);
                String You = "<font color='red'>you</font>?";
                dlgAlert.setMessage("How are " + Html.fromHtml(You));
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Mood");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Good",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {


                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setNeutralButton("Okay",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Bad",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.create().show();
```

It's not changing the word "you" to the color red. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it

In your `Activity`:

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View dialog = factory.inflate(R.layout.example_dialog, null);
TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Test 123");  
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 1, 0);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 1, 2, 0);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.DKGRAY), 2, 3, 0);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), 3, 4, 0);

title.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialog)
       .setTitle("Title")
       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  // Do something
              }
        })
       .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              }
        })
       .create()
       .show();
```

In /layouts/example_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#F70000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also set the TextColor using `Html.fromHtml`

```
title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Test</font><font color='blue'>ing</font>"));
```

The title can also have a custom View for the title, you set it with `setCustomTitle(View view)`

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do without custom alert boxes, which is illustrated here: http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/

Comment: That seems to be for an Alert dialog on a web page.

Comment: Yeah I realized my mistake after commenting, but "delete" only seemed to call a vote to delete comments and I wasn't sure if that was the right course of action.